# Arranging keys on a keyboard

Tags: probability

This is the question:

> Ari randomly arranges the Q, W, E, R, T, and Y keys on his keyboard. What is the probability that exactly one key remains in its original position?

**My Try:** Let's say we want Q to stay in its original position, then the ways to arrange W, E, R, T, and Y such that the keys don't stay in their original positionis $!5 = 44$ (this is called derangements). So our probability is $\frac{44*6}{6!} = \frac{11}{30}$. However the answer key states that the answer is $\frac{5}{24}$, and I don't know why.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are correct!

Comment: I agree; you have the correct answer.

Comment: $\tfrac{!5}{5!}$ is the correct answer.  I have no idea where they came up with $\tfrac{5}{4!}$.